# SQL- finding missing values and grouping

Tags: sql

[image]

I have to get span for a person based on the missing value. As per my requirement, for person 101 the min start date is 6/1/2019 so his first span will begin at 6/1/2019 . Person 101 has start dates for the subsequent months till Aug , for Sep there is no start date .Hence, his first span will end at last day of last available month until missing one which is AUG and enddate for his span1 will be 8/31/2019. Person101 again receive start date in Oct so his new span will begin at 10/1/2019 and will continue till Dec as that's his max month of start date for span2 and his end date for span2 will be 12/31/2019.
Looking for some hints to implement this in SQL. Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: This looks like a [gaps and islands](https://mattboegner.com/improve-your-sql-skills-master-the-gaps-islands-problem/) type of problem.